# Electron: How can i detect new window open and prevent it

Tags: electron

I am searching how to prevent and get url if new tab is opened.
Not in my index.js in a webview in HTML and JS.

new-window event does not work.

Comment: So, am I reading this question right, that you want to prohibit users from navigating away from inside a `WebView`, opening a new tab? If so, this most likely will have to take place in the main process, since such APIs are no longer exposed to the renderer process. But please clarify if that's actually what you want to do.

Comment: If someone clicks on a _blank target link i want to get the url and not open a new window. And this is in my HTML in a <webview> tag.